Ambiguity of "not.... because" by Winston Churchill
I came across this speech given Winston Churchill to the Canadian Parliament

The peoples of the British Empire may love peace. They do not seek the
lands or wealth of any country, but they are a tough and hardy lot. We
have not journeyed all this way across the centuries, across the
oceans, across the mountains, across the prairies, because we are made
of sugar candy.

I think with the context of "We have not journeyed all this way across the centuries, across the oceans, across the mountains, across the prairies, because we are made of sugar candy.", the meaning is clear.
Because he said they are a tough and hardy lot before "we have not ...", I assume the meaning of "not ... because" here means we have journeyed all this way across the centuries ... not because we are made of sugar candy (but because we are tough and hardy).
I also read a similar quote from David McCullough's "The American Spirit: Who We Are and What We Stand For", the chapter 4 "which way forward"

"We didn't come this far because we're made of sugar candy."


It was quoted without contexts, but with the first quote in mind I would assume the meaning is we come this far not because we are made of sugar candy. Is that correct?
BTW, I find the similar question here Ambiguity of “not.... because” but I hope someone who knows Winston Churchill well may give me more explanation.

This is answered by context. And the link to the other question you've attached makes it clear.

I can't find the context of "We didn't come this far because we're made of sugar candy.", part of reason I asked in the first place.

If you want the source of a Churchill quote you should ask on History or Literature SE. The rest is a duplicate, unless you can explain what you want to know that isn't explained.

Actually I first asked my question at History SE, but I got several down-votes and some useless comments (partly because I didn't  ask my question clearly). I was a bit upset and annoyed too and considering to delete my question. Then I got an answer, which made me realized that was probably a language question! So I asked here, but if folks here think my question here is duplicated I will delete it later.

This question is similar to: Ambiguity of “not.... because”. The statement is inherently ambiguous, and disambiguated by context in the first instance. Answers that need to know the mind of an author belong on Lit, not ELU.

It is classic Brit understatement, and you can take anything Churchill said at any time as gorgeous use of the language. Also, read "because" as based on: our successes are hardly (not) based on (because of) being fragile. The understatement teases the reader to conclude We don't melt or crumble rather than telling them outright that they are tough.

You can't use the phrase "we didn't come this far" if you didn't actually come this far. "this far" refers to your current place, so it makes no sense to say you haven't achieved it.
So it must mean that they did come this far. And just as in the more extensive quote, he's saying that it's because they're made of better stuff than sugar candy.
In addition, it should be clear that the quote is supposed to be inspirational. You don't generally inspire with negative statements.

I further search the second quote and find this article  , "After the attack on Pearl Harbor, Winston Churchill said that the American people–he said, “We didn’t come this far because we are made of sugar candy.”" Not sure if that was real though.

My initial thought was that McCullough was paraphrasing Churchill, or just didn't remember the exact phrasing and recounted this shorter form from his memory.

This indeed sounds like more reasonable explanation.


we come this far not because we are made of sugar candy.

Your interpretation should be rather as follows.

we have come this far  because we are not made of sugar candy. (understated: "we are made of a tougher substance")

There are at least three interpretations for the use of this conjunction and the context is the key to understanding. Those three that i have in mind will be shown now. In certain contexts the normal interpretation only is possible (1.), in others a second one (2.a-) is only possible. In another type of sentence two interpretations are possible, the normal one (1.) and a variant of "2. a-" (2.b-). By themselves such sentences can be ambiguous.
A

We did not light the fire because it was warm.


We did not light the fire and the reason is that it was warm.

B

We did not light the fire because it was cold .


a- We did light the fire and the reason is not that it was cold (or "could have been cold"). (May be the reason was that they thought to be adding a romantic touch in the room by doing so, but the cold was not a problem (It was not cold enough for them perhaps, or not cold at all). You may go on with something like, for instance, "We just felt like having a fire.".)

A context of contradiction in terms (no fire/ cold) points to an interpretation of the second type (a) (two options, the reason is realized or it is not).
C

We did not speak loudly because we were shy, intimidated beginners. (two interpretations)


It is a fact that we did not speak loudly and the reason for that is that we were shy, intimidated beginners.
b- It is a fact that we did speak loudly and (obviously) the reason for that could not be that we should have been  shy, intimidated beginners. (You may go on as follows: "We were used to make ourselves heard in such circumstances.", or with any other  explanation that is proper)

In "2. b-" the two opposites in the subordinate are not an option: only the negative one obtains. This is the case of Churchill's sentence.
